# Importing Database and its table to another PC/Laptop

Tags: php, mysql, database

How do I import it to another pc? 
I tried getting/copying the folder of the database from xampp/mysql/data/"FOLDERNAME".

But after I paste it to the same `path(xampp/mysql/data/)` on the computer, it couldn't find the table.

This is what I did, my friend sent me its database folder from `xampp/mysql/data/sportswebsite`

After that, I paste it on my laptop's `xampp/mysql/data` then go to `localhost/phpmyadmin`. I found the `sportswebsite` database name, but when I click on one of its table I get an error of :
`Table 'sportswebsite.user' doesn't exist in engine.`

Why is that?

Comment: Use the export feature in phpmyadmin, take a look at this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffmCGVse8yg)

Comment: A for Effort! Thanks :)

Comment: Easier than to make print screens, next time I`ll go for the A+ :)